# SVM in R - Classify new instance

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I built my SVM model using the code below:

```
X1 = c(2, 2, -2, -2, 1, 1, -1, -1)
X2 = c(2, -2, -2, 2, 1, -1, -1, 1)
Y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
alldata = data.frame(X1, X2, Y)
svm_model <- svm(alldata$Y ~ . , kernel = "radial", type = "C-classification", alldata)
```

Now, I want to classify the new instance with values `(4,5)`. I tried by using the command:

```
predict(svm_model, c(4,5))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Next thing I did is create a small data frame like below, tried to classify and got the result shown:

```
b1 = c(4)
b2 = c(5)
b = data.frame(b1,b2)
predict(svm_model, b)
   1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
   1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2
```

Where am I making the mistake ?

Comment: The names of the variables you use in your formula need to match exactly the names used in your new data.frame for the predict (otherwise how does R know which values map to which variables). Try `b = data.frame(X1=b1,X2=b2)`. Also you should just use `Y ~ .` as the formula (don't use `$`) and just set `data=alldata`. This makes using functions like predict much safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message indicates that `c(4,5)` is not containing the same information as in `alldata` you use for training. More specifically, the `colnames()` are not the same.

By creating a new dataframe:

`new_data <- data.frame(X1 = 4, X2 = 5)` you will be able to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same variables X1 and X2 in your 'b' data frame to predict. Replace b1 and b2 in your code with X1 and X2.

```
X1 = c(4)
X2 = c(5)
b = data.frame(X1,X2)

predict(svm_model, b)
```